# Background page runs, but popup says 'You do not have a background page.' when using getBackgroundPage()

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, web-extension

I have a very simple background page for a Chrome extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener((reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
});
```

The background page runs when my extension is loaded:
[image]

The extension also has a popup that runs [getBackgroundPage()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getBackgroundPage), using:

```
const serviceWorkerWindow = await chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage();
```

This fails with:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: You do not have a background page.
```

How do I make `getBackgroundPage()` work?

Comment: ManifestV3 extensions don't have a background page, they have a background script which is a service worker not a page, so getBackgroundPage is meaningless. How did you plan to use it? There may be a different solution e.g. navigator.serviceWorker messaging.

Comment: Manifest V3 uses service workers, but they are defined using the term `background` and the documented APIs for v3 should work. My use case is to communicate with the background page / service worker. See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getBackgroundPage

Comment: Thing is there's no page, so this API won't work. There's no such thing as serviceWorkerWindow either. The documentation is simply outdated because the ManifestV3 team consists of just a few devs who don't have time to do everything. To communicate with the background script you can use [extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or navigator.serviceWorker messaging.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm I'll try that. Sad to read the documentation isn't maintained properly.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I used `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` in the popup and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()` in the extension. Knowing that the documentation was outdated (and that `You do not have a background page` was misleading) was critical to trying other ways to communicate to the background page. If you turn your comment into an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Further information: [extension.getBackgroundPage, runtime.getBackgroundPage, and serviceWorkers](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/295)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answering my own question based on @wOxxOm's comment. If wOxxOm writes their own answer I'll mark that as correct.*

My expectation [based on Google's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getBackgroundPage) was that `getBackgroundPage()`:

> retrieves the JavaScript 'window' object for the background page running inside the current extension/app.

In modern JS terms, this would be the `globalThis` for the service worker (the service workers is still referred to as `background` in manifest v3.

As wOxxOm said.

> **This API won't work. The documentation is simply outdated because the ManifestV3 team consists of just a few devs who don't have time to do everything.**

Essentially the Chrome Extension documentation is not adequately maintained. There is an [outstanding W3C issue on the topic of whether `getBackgroundPage` should work with service workers](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/295) - thanks @erosman. The best way to communicate between a popup and a background service worker is via [extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Ie:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage()
```

And:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getBackgroundPage()` method doesn't retrieve the background script, it [retrieves the `window` object associated with the background script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getBackgroundPage:%7E:text=Retrieves%20the%20JavaScript%20%27window%27%20object%20for%20the%20background%20page). As you know, Manifest V3 doesn't use background scripts, it uses a service worker. Service workers by definition [do not have access to window objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527792/workers-web-or-service-anyway-to-access-window-object).

What is your use case? Maybe I could suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: MV3 extensions do have a background script (that's why it's still declared in `background` section of manifest.json), the difference is that it doesn't belong to a page, but instead is a service worker script.

Comment: Your answer isn't an answer, but to respond: yes, I'm aware `getBackgroundPage()` returns the window of the background page, hence `const serviceWorkerWindow =` in the question. I am trying to get the serviceWorkers's `window` from the popup - as mentioned in the question. I am not trying to access the DOM in the service worker. Background pages do have a `window`, it's just not the popup's `window` or the pages `window`, see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getBackgroundPage also mentioned in the question.

Comment: I did understand the question. What I'm trying to get across is that a service as a background script is like a web platform service worker in that it cannot access `window` or the DOM even if it is called a background script.

Comment: @StormyKnight I might have been a little harsh / unwelcoming here and I apologize. I genuinely believed Google's documentation was correct - when Google said "Retrieves the JavaScript 'window' object for the background page" I thought they meant the JS global object for the background service worker. I still don't think your answer was much of an answer, but I think my tone was off - sorry about that.

Comment: @mikemaccana I actually debated whether I should give a proper answer or just make a comment. At the time, I didn't think the question was answerable as currently phrased, which is why I made it an answer and ended my answer by asking for a use case.